# Syntax error in php yii, concatenating strings

Tags: php, yii, syntax-error

I get Syntax error in php yii, concatenating strings

```
 echo "<h1>Welcome </h1>" . Yii::app->user->name;
```

Comment: It would be nice to include the actual error in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `Yii::app()->user->name;`